# Get Product ID from Customer Order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, googlestrustedstore

I am setting up Google trusted stores and I am stuck on one problem which is not compulsory but I would rather it was working.

I need to **get the product ID of the item the customer has ordered**

So far I have this:

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

and I guess I need to get the product ID with something like...`$order->get**productID**()`

Also what would happen if there is multiple products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following after your code:

```
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
$productIds = array();
foreach($items as $i) {
      $productIds[] = $i->getProductId();
}
```

The  `$productIds` array will contain all the product ids from the order.

Comment: Do I need the sqaure brackets when I echo `$productIds` ?

Comment: @MikeTimTurner Just do `print_r($productIds)` to get the values of the array.

Comment: `echo $productIds;` is what I needed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

To get all products from the order, in my case I allow for all incoming orders, I did the following. Allows for more flexibility.

```
            $order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids');
            foreach($order_ids as $order_id) {
                echo '<P>'.$order_id;
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
                $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    echo '<P>'.$item->getProductId();
                }
              }
```